# All values of JSON data are not inserted in MySQL Database (for UTF-8 characters)

Tags: php, mysql, json, database, utf-8

I get a text from a database in UTF-8 using JSON and it is in a file right now. When I print the data it is:

> توحید در نگاه امام علی (علیه السلام)

But when I insert it in database I get this error:

> Insertion Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '�وحید در نگاه امام علی ' at line 1

This is my code

```
<?php 
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","bbbbbbb","bbbbbbb");
mysql_select_db("db", $con);
if(file_exists('./json/file.json')){
    $jsondata = file_get_contents('./json/file.json');
    $data = json_decode($jsondata, true);
    foreach ($data['nodes'] as $node){
        $data_element = $node['node'];
        $title = $data_element['title'];
        $summary = $data_element['summary'];
        $body = $data_element['body'];
        $id = $data_element['id'];
        print $title."\n";
        $insert = "INSERT INTO main(title) VALUES ($title)";
        mysql_query($insert) or die("Insertion Error: ". mysql_error());
    }
}
else 
    print "File doesn't exist";
```

The database and its columns are all `utf8_general_ci`. Why the printed text is not same as the one that is inserted in Database?

Comment: I can't understand, how it can work, if you do this query - "INSERT INTO main(title) VALUES (توحید در نگاه امام علی (علیه السلام))". Is it vulnerable to sql injections?

Comment: `$insert = "INSERT INTO main(title) VALUES ($title)";` simply will not work -- because there are no quotes around `$title`.

Comment: @RickJames it is exactly what I missed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The database-connection needs to know it is utf8 too. `mysql_set_charset('utf8')`.

Instead of the deprecated mysql_con, you should have a look at [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

Comment: Perfect answer, but please could you edit this to include a warning of the deprecated mysql extension

Comment: I tried it, but it gave me this error `Error : (1064) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'در نگاه امام علی (علیه السلام))' at line 1`

Comment: By modifying the insertion query to `$insert = "INSERT INTO main(title) VALUES ('$title')";` it worked. thanks

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","","your_db_name");

$mysqli->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

<strike>$mysqli->query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");</strike>

Comment: You can do it, but in this case this queries will be executed on each request, so 10000 requests will be equal to 20000 additional queries. Better configure your sql server to use this globally, than set it each time.

Comment: this is set only once in config.php and include config once in page

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: If I will request your page 10 times, how much times it will be executed?

Comment: I tried it, but it gave me this error `Error : (1064) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'در نگاه امام علی (علیه السلام))' at line 1`

Answer (score 1):

Although @ericwenn and @SahilManchal bring up valid points, the immediate error is the failure to quote the string in `... VALUES ($title) ...`.

Do not blindly put a *string* into the query.

This will work but it is *not* safe:  `... VALUES ('$title') ...`.  It is subject to a hack called "sql injection".  See `real_escape_string`.

Also, after connecting *with mysqli*, use

```
$mysqli->set_charset('utf8');
```

That is preferable to `SET NAMES`.

Comment: I tried it, but it gave me this error `Error : (1064) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'در نگاه امام علی (علیه السلام))' at line 1`